# Access to private variables of Objects that are within a private array

Tags: java, arrays, private, private-members

I want to create a Restaurant object that can have multiple menus. Each menu can have multiple categories, and each category can have multiple items. Each item will have a name, price, and description.

```
--Company--
  -Menu ONE-
  -Menu Name-
    -Category ONE-
       -Category Name-
       -Menu Item ONE-
         -Menu Item Name
         -Menu Item Price
         -Menu Item Description
       -Menu Item TWO-
    -Category TWO-
  -Menu TWO-
```

Example classes without constructors, getters / setters, or methods.

A company that holds an array of menus

```
    public class Company
    {   
        // Class constants

        // Class variables
        private String companyName;   //  Stores company name
        private String hours;         //  Restaurant hours
        private String phoneNumber;   //  Restaurant phone number
        private Menu[] menuList;      //  Array of menu objects
        private int menuCount;        //  Number of menus in the array

     }
```

A menu which holds an array of Categories

```
    public class Menu
    {   
        // Class constants

        // Class variables
        private String menuName;           //  Name of Menu
        private Category[] categoryList;   //  Array of category objects
        private int categoryCount;         //  Number of categories in the array

     }
```

A category which holds an array of Menu Items

```
    public class Category
    {   
        // Class constants

        // Class variables
        private String categoryName;       //  Name of Menu
        private MenuItem[] menItemList;    //  Array of MenuItem objects
        private int menuItemCount;         //  Number of menu items in the array

     }
```

A single line item with a name, price, and description

```
    public class MenuItem
    {   
        // Class constants

        // Class variables
        private String name;        //  Name of Menu Item
        private float price;        //  Price of the Menu Item
        private String description; //  Description of the Menu Item

     }
```

In the driver class, how would I change anything in Menu Item, if I only have access to Company's methods?

I thought about having a getter for each private array of items, but digging down 3 levels into private arrays seems very difficult to implement. It's not as simple as Company.Menu.Category.MenuItem.editName(newName);

Note* I'm not interested in "Should use a Linked list or ArrayList" answers. The program requirements call for basic arrays.

Let me know if I need to be more clear or if you want a SSCCE.

Comment: The more complex the data structure, the complex the ETL. Using getter/setters and digging down is your best bet.

Comment: Use getters/setters to access the private member variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought about having a getter for each private array of items, but
>   digging down 3 levels into private arrays seems very difficult to
>   implement. It's not as simple as
>   Company.Menu.Category.MenuItem.editName(newName);

It is not difficult to implement but it is an anti pattern to invoke successively getters such as :

```
company.getMenu().getCategory().getMenuItem().editName(newName);
```

The [Demeter law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)  states as :

> Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only
>   units "closely" related to the current unit.
>
> Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
>
> Only talk to your immediate friends.

So to solve your issue, you will have to refactor your design to make collaborate your objects from the one to the other.

**Collaborating/Cascading approach**

You could define a `editItemName()` method that is successively invoked by each object of the hierarchy.

`Company` could define the method such as :

```
public void editItemName(String menuName, String categoryName, String itemName, String newName){ 
   Menu menu = findMenu(menuName);
   menu.editItemName(category, item, newName);
}
```

`Menu` could define the method such as :

```
public void editItemName(String categoryName, String itemName, String newName){ 
   Category category = findCategory(categoryName);
   category.editItemName(item, newName);
}
```

`Category` could define the method such as :

```
public void editItemName(String itemName, String newName){ 
   MenuItem item = findItem(itemName);
   item.editItemName(newName);
}
```

And at last `MenuItem` could define the method such as :

```
public void editItemName(String newName){
   this.name = newName;
}
```

**Straighter approach (if suitable)**

Passing so many arguments may be cumbersome for clients.
As alternative if `Item` objects are unique (in terms of `equals()`) and you can get it from the client side, you could make things still simpler.
You could need to define only the method in `MenuItem` (the leaf) as :

```
public void editItemName(String newName){
   this.name = newName;
}
```

You could define a Map that store the items by their identifier :

```
Map<String, MenuItem> mapUniqueItems = new HashMap<>();
// add items in the map
mapUniqueItems.put("item1", new MenuItem(..));
mapUniqueItems.put("item2", new MenuItem(..));
// add items in the hierarchy as you actually do
...
```

And later you can edit an item from its id, for example :

```
String itemIdentifier = ...;
MenuItem item = mapUniqueItems.get(itemIdentifier);
item.editItemName("new value");
```

Comment: getters and setters arent inherently violating the law of demeter. If A calls B.get and B calls C.get then everything is fine. Its when A calls C.get that it violates the law

Comment: I refer to plain getters. To invoke C from A you have to invoke `A.getB().getC()`; What you refer is `A.getCfromB()` and this is not a  dumb getter. It is a retrieval method that performs more logic.

Comment: I see... I assumed OP was talking about the second kind

Comment: @avigil  In fact, the OP is not specific. So it is interpretation free I think. I edited to be more specific about this point.

Comment: @davidxxx if I do `MenuItem item = mapUniqueItems.get(itemId);` Does that perform a shallow copy of the object allowing for editing of it's members?

Comment: @BillSkiCO If you added in a `Map` the items and you retrieve it from, it will not return the copy but the actual `MenuItem` object.

Answer (score 1):

You have to dig down to get the information you want out of the Menu object, provided that you create getter methods for the members that must be read from outside. That's the point of encapsulation. You can create a helper class / method to manage the various levels of your array if these operations will be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Chaining of `.` is a bad practice to avood it you can do something like below

create method  `modifyMenu`  in class Company

```
  public class Company {
       public modifyMenu (int menuIndexToModify, int categoryIndex, MenuItem itemWithModification){
            menuList[menuIndexToModify].modifyMenuItem(categoryIndex, menuItemIndex, itemWithModification);
      }
  }
```

create method `modifyMenuItem` in  `Menu` class

```
 public class Menu{
    public void modifyMenuItem(int categoryIndex, int menuItemIndex, MenuItem itemWithModification){
              categoryList[categoryIndex].modifyMenuItem(menuItemIndex,itemWithModification);
    }
 }
```

Create `modifyMenuItem` method in Class `Category`

```
public class Category{
    public void modifyMenuItem(int menuItemIndex, MenuItem itemWithModification){
            menuItemList[menuItemIndex].modify(itemWithModification);
     }
 }
```

Crete method `modify` in `MenuItem`

```
 public void modify( MenuItem itemWithModification){
      this.name = itemWithModification.name
      // assign other stes similarly
 }
```

Now you just need to invoke method `modifyMenu` , pass the parameters to it.